# What is the lowest time complexity to square and sum every element in an array, for every array in a 2D array, then sum the results?

Tags: python, time-complexity

So for example, if I had `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, the steps would be as follows:

1. `[[1, 4, 9],[16, 25, 36]]` <- square every element
2. `[[14],[77]]` <- sum every array
3. 99 <- sum the arrays

What's the lowest time complexity this can be done in?

Comment: Seems obviously `O(n)` (or `O(mn)` if you want to express in terms of rows and columns). Why do you ask?

Comment: Do you need the intermediates?

Comment: How would I do it in O(n)? Thanks!

Comment: You could do it in one line: `sum(sum(i**2 for i in nums) for nums in num_lists)`